# sorting javascript array slice

Tags: javascript, sorting, slice

In trying to create a sortable table, I am sorting the underlying array of data:

```
var g = [
   [ 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Id', 'Age'],
   [ 'Joe', 'Blogs', '1', 24],
   [ 'Fred', 'Frog', '2', 18],
];
```

I want to sort everything except the header.

```
g = g.sort(mycomparison);
```

is no good, though I could change the comparison routine to always put element[0] in front of everything else.

Instead, I would like to sort everything except the header.  The following seems to do what I want, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to express this in javascript.  I want to sort the last n-1 elements.

```
g = g.slice(0,1).concat(g.slice(1,g.length-1).sort(mycomparison))
```

Comment: I'm asking for the best way to express this in javascript.  The above line seems a bit crazy, but that's the best I could come up with.

Comment: I would do `shift()`/`unshift()`, the code would look more readable IMHO

Comment: Or just skip sorting the first one `g.sort(function(a,b) { return a === g[0] ? 0 : a[0].localeCompare(b[0]); });`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8jkhfr9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in another way which looks a bit tidier, see this following **underscore.js** way:

```
g =  [].concat(_.first(g), _sort(_.tail(g), mycomparison ));
```

Using underscore does not help improving performance but it just simplifies and makes your code a bit more readable. From the example above, I believe it makes sense to people who even don't usually use underscore.

It's straightforward and semantic so people read it and understand instantly that *it splits the first, and the rest of array g, sort the rest and re-join them*. (To me it looks more readable than vanilla JavaScript)